# Python: How to know if two dictionary have the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic1 = {'a':'a','b':'c','c':'d'}
dic2 = {'b':'a','a':'c','c':'d'}

dic1.keys()    =>['a', 'b', 'c']
dic2.keys()    =>['b', 'a', 'c']
```

dic1 and dic2 have the same keys, but in different order.

How to tell they have same keys(do not consider the order)?

Comment: Do not sort the keys(), if possible.

Comment: Why not? It *is* possibly to not sort the key, but that's a weird and arbitrary restriction. Is this homework?

Comment: "dic1 and dic2 have the same keys, but in different order." - this is a non-sense in a python dictionary - the keys are not ordered.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

python 2.7

**[dict views](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):**
Supports direct set operations, etc.

```
>>> dic1 = {'a':'a','b':'c','c':'d'}
>>> dic2 = {'b':'a','a':'c','c':'d'}
>>> dic1.viewkeys() == dic2.viewkeys()
True
>>> dic1.viewkeys() - dic2.viewkeys()
set([])
>>> dic1.viewkeys() | dic2.viewkeys()
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

**similarly in 3.x:**  (thx @lennart)

```
>>> dic1 = {'a':'a','b':'c','c':'d'}
>>> dic2 = {'b':'a','a':'c','c':'d'}
>>> dic1.keys() == dic2.keys()
True
>>> dic1.keys() - dic2
set()
>>> dic1.keys() | dic2
{'a', 'c', 'b'}
```

python 2.4+

**[set operation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):** direct iteration over dict keys into a set

```
>>> dic1 = {'a':'a','b':'c','c':'d'}
>>> dic2 = {'b':'a','a':'c','c':'d'}
>>> set(dic1) == set(dic2)
True
```

Comment: It's just called "keys()" in Python 3.

Answer (score 12):

```
set(dic1.keys()) == set(dic2.keys())
```

Comment: @Summer : the keys of a dict cannot contain duplicated elements, by the definition of a dict.

Comment: Yes, but keys() method returns a list and I can't guarantee, that items in two lists are in the same order. That's why using a set.

Answer (score 1):

We can use all

```
all( k in dic2 for k in dic1) and all(k in dic1 for k in dic2)
```

Comment: One could go and len(dic1) == len(dic2) for the second half

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you ended making `keys()` return you an unsorted list but `sorted(dict1.keys()) == sorted(dict2.keys())` should do it.

Comment: `sorted()` is **O(n lgn),** whereas `set()` is only **O(n).** Of course, [you shouldn't use either under Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656478/2809027) – unless you explicitly know you're dealing with `OrderedDict` instances or an analogue thereof, in which case [gruszczy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98494/gruszczy)'s [`set()`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656353/2809027) is *substantially* more optimal.